# Gitlab pipeline job not being triggered even though its showing up when simulating pipeline run

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am running a pipeline in one of my projects.
I have encountered a problem where the build job is not being run, despite it showing up when doing a simulation with the gitlab lint tool.
Unfortunately I cant paste the whole gitlab.ci file, as it contains sensitive information.
Has anybody encountered something similar before?

This is the build job:

```
build:
  stage: build
  extends: .docker
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "schedule"
  script:
    - docker build --build-arg NODE_ENV=${ENV_TAG} --build-arg NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV} --build-arg ENV_TAG=${ENV_TAG} -f Dockerfile --cache-from $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$ENV_TAG -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$ENV_TAG -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$ENV_TAG-$CI_COMMIT_SHA -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA .
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE --all-tags
```

I have tried changing the rules of the job, but that ended up making the gitlab.ci invalid or not running the job even in the simulation.

Comment: Does `.docker` perhaps have an `only` or `except` field? Also, are the jobs that should run before the `build` job, successful? Also, what does your `stages` value look like?

Comment: Try wrapping your command arguments that contain [special characters](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/script.html#use-special-characters-with-script) like `:` in single quotes (`'`) as well.

Comment: @DMalan my stages is the following:

    stages:
      - build
      - test
      - import
      - deploy
      - post_deploy

The .docker job doesnt have any only or except fields. The build stage runs as the first stage and doesnt have any previous jobs.

Comment: Also the quotes shouldnt be the problem, as the build job works on all other branches. My issue only occurs on the main branch, on all other branches it works

Comment: Do you have any other conditions for the main branch anywhere else in your Gitlab file? I don't think it's possible to really help if we can't see the entire file.

Comment: Do you see the runner attached to this job?